# Show prerelease version in the package.json Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense, package.json

Is there any way to show a prerelease version in the Intellisense when I'm editing package.json in VS2017? It would be helpful when I'm searching for a new packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it would not have this feature, what I know is that we could get it from the Nuget package for the pre-release version numbers, but not from the intellisense. Maybe you could submit your feature request here:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. The Visual Studio product team is listening to user voice there. You can send your idea there and people can vote.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and navigation to the forum. I'll post the feature request soon.